# Scala Replacing an object in a list

Tags: scala, json4s

I have a List of JValues in scala with the following format: 
`[{ id: "foo" values: {...}}, {}]`

I want to go through the list, and, if the id is equal to a certain value, replace the values.  In Java, I have this code

```
newList = List()

for (item in list) {
  if (item.id == id) { 
    newList.add(newValues)

  }
  else {
    newList.add(item)
  }
}
```

}
}

How would I do this in Scala?

Comment: Assuming your list is Scala immutable list, you can use the `map` on the list to create a new list. Inside your `map` you pass a function that does the check you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
val ary: JArray = //some value
ary.children.map {
    case JObject if myid == JObject.getField("id") => new JObject(myid, newvalue)
    case other => other
}
```